# Reuse inline image in IPython notebook

Tags: image, matplotlib, inline, ipython

Is it possible to create an inline png image, e.g. using matplotlib, and re-using it in a markdown cell (via html) without saving it on hard disk first?

IPython notebook saves inline images in the ipynb file, so the data is available, I wonder if it is also accessible?

One idea is to generate images for pretty slides (cell mode) and to to suppress the slides for image creation.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible without saving the image. Using slide mode you can exclude some cells. is is also possible to use slide-mode and not to show the code if you are using custom templates.